# Dynamically select properties from PHP object

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of PHP objects (lets say orders) which have arrays of items like so (JSON for ease of notation):

```
$orders = [
  {
    id: 87,
    user_id: 6,
    menu_id: 9,
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Item 1",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 88,
    user_id: 3,
    menu_id: 6,
    items: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Item 2",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to make a CSV row with titles of this kind of array. I'm using a keyed array like so:

```
$settings = [
  'Order ID' => 'id',
  'User ID' => 'user_id'
];
```

So now I can go...

```
$csv = [];
$csv[] = array_keys($settings);

foreach($orders as $order):

    $csv_row = [];

    foreach($settings as $column);
      $csv_row[] = $order->{$column};
    endforeach;

    $csv[] = $csv_row;

endforeach;
```

This gives me:

```
[ 'Order ID',   'User ID' ]
[ '87',         '6' ]
[ '88',         '3' ]
```

Is there any way I can dynamically access the 'deeper' variables? i.e. `$order->items[0]->name`, in a similar way to the curly bracket notation? I need to do it dynamically as there are lots of different object and relations that I need to export as CSV files.

<sub>P.S. Its really late – sorry if this is a crazy question</sub>

Comment: they're just arrays, so `$order[0]['name']`? You can't build that kind of array "path" dynamically without resorting to evil stuff like `eval`, but if you know how "deep" into the array you have to go, you can easy do `$order[$a][$b][$c]...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the curly braces notation to get deeper than one level. What you could do is to use a helper function that would let you **fetch values by multi-level key**.

An example function could be:

```
function getByPath($value, array $path)
{ 
  if (empty($path)) return $value;
  if (!is_array($value)) return;
  if (array_key_exists($path[0], $value)) return getByPath($value[$path[0]], array_slice($path, 1));
}
```

Example usage pattern for your case could be:

```
$settings = [
  'Order ID' => ['id'],
  'User ID' => ['user', 'id'],
  'User Name' => ['user', 'name'],
  'Item 0 Name' => ['item', 0, 'name'],
  'Item 0 Price' => ['item', 0, 'price']
];

foreach($settings as $path);
  $csv_row[] = getByPath($order, $path);
endforeach;
```

Comment: basically what I was about to say.  slightly different code.

Comment: If you weren't stuck in the internet, I would kiss you.